# How to write a query with conditions such as A And (B Or C) with Spring Data query methods?

Tags: spring-data

Based on the [Spring Data documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/), it is easy to do conditions such as A Or B. Example:

```
List<Person> findByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastname, String firstname);
```

I wouild like to know how to write a query with conditions A And (B Or C). Something like the following:

```
List<Person> findByEmailAddressAnd(LastnameOrFirstname)(String emailAddress, String lastname, String firstname);
```

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@Query` annotation.

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.emailAddress=:emailAddress AND (p.lastName=:lastName OR p.firstName=:firstName)")
List<Person> findByEmailAddressAnd(LastnameOrFirstname)(String emailAddress, String lastname, String firstname);
```

Comment: manish, thanks for chiming in! Is it true that writing Query like yours is the only way Spring Data handles my situation?  Shouldn't you use Param to annotate arguments in the method?

Comment: Yes, using `@Query` annotations is the only option for running queries that have groups (anything that needs to be written within brackets) with any of the Spring Data modules.  This is due to the way method names are broken down into tokens to be matched against entity and attribute names.  Even if there was a mechanism to generate such queries by parsing a method name, my guess is that it would be too ugly.  In the interest of keeping the code readable and understandable for future needs, I would still code a query like this in a SQL-like format, which is what the `@Query` annotation does.